# Execute parallel tasks without waiting for results in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

Is there a possibility to execute parallel tasks (e.g. `async`) without waiting until all threads have finished? I want to parallelize a timed function call, e.g. a thread has to wait some time before doing the job and repeat it if necessary (can take several seconds or minutes). Or are there other ways to achieve it?

Here my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Item
{
public:
  int id;
  int delayTime; // in ms
  int cycles;    // number of repetitions
};

class JobManager
{
private:
  std::vector<Item> fItems;
public:
  JobManager()
  {
    Item item1, item2;
    item1.id = 12;
    item1.cycles = 3;
    item1.delayTime = 2000; 
    fItems.push_back(item1);

    item2.id = 34;
    item2.cycles = 2;
    item2.delayTime = 25000;
    fItems.push_back(item2);
  }
  ~JobManager() {}
  void DoJob(Item& item) {std::cout << "Item " << item.id << "(thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ")" << " is doing the job." << std::endl; }

  void Start(Item& item)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(item.delayTime)); // wait some time

    for (int i = 0; i < item.cycles; i++) // repeat the job
    {
      DoJob(item);
    }
  }

  void Run()
  {
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    for (auto &it : fItems)
    {
      futures.push_back(std::async(&JobManager::Start, this, std::ref(it)));
    }

    // DON'T WANT TO WAIT
    //std::for_each(futures.begin(), futures.end(), [](std::future<void> & fut)
    //{
    //    fut.wait();
    //});
  }
};

int main()
{
  JobManager m;

  // real method receives a message from network
  // so it can be simulated as loop, something like
  while(true)
  {
    m.Run();
    Sleep(3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to stop the application terminating after calling m.Run()?  but without waiting for child threads to complete?

Comment: How about just making detached threads?

Comment: Given I understand @alex555 correctly that would not help. The application will terminate cleaning all thread based resources (even copied).

Comment: @Corvusoft: No, I want the application immidiateley to continue after `m.Run()`. But without waiting. Commenting out of `fut.wait();` means that function woun't called. See updated code.

Comment: The easiest way for me would be to have a vector of flags: for each , when there are no flags left then carry on with the rest of the codethread run add a flag to the vector, when each completes have it remove a flag, or to save memory just have an integer and do some threadcounting: add to the int var when threads start and subtract from it when the finish and when it is 0 you can carry on with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A std::thread based implementation should do the trick.

**Example**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

using std::ref;
using std::hash;
using std::bind;
using std::vector;
using std::thread;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;
using std::chrono::seconds;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

struct Job
{
    int id;
    int cycles;
    milliseconds delayTime;
};

class JobManager
{
    public:
        JobManager( void ) : m_jobs( ), m_workers( )
        {
            m_jobs.push_back( { 12, 3, milliseconds( 2000 ) } );
            m_jobs.push_back( { 34, 2, milliseconds( 5000 ) } );
        }

        virtual ~JobManager( void )
        {
            for ( auto worker : m_workers )
            {
                worker->join( );
            }
        }

        void DoJob( Job& job )
        {
            auto thread_id = hash< thread::id >( )( std::this_thread::get_id( ) ); 

            printf( "Job %i (thread %lu) is doing the job.\n", job.id, thread_id );
        }

        void Start( Job& job )
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( job.delayTime );

            for ( int cycle_count = 0; cycle_count < job.cycles; cycle_count++ )
            {
                DoJob( job );
            }
        }

        void Run( void )
        {
            for ( auto &job : m_jobs )
            {
                auto worker = std::make_shared< thread >( bind( &JobManager::Start, this, ref( job ) ) );

                m_workers.push_back( worker );
            }
        }

    private:
        vector< Job > m_jobs;

        vector< shared_ptr< thread > > m_workers;
};

int main( int, char** )
{
    JobManager manager;
    manager.Run( );

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( seconds( 10 ) );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Build**

> g++ -o example example.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread

**References**

[std::thread api reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)